# ListBox copy item to clipboard

Tags: wpf, mvvm, listbox

I would like to allow for listboxitem to be copied to clipboard. I have a listbox that already uses a datatemplate. Can any one give me a pointer on how this can be done in MVVM?

Comment: You don't "copy" the UI into the clipboard, because UI is not data. Just copy your data in whatever format you like.

Comment: http://elegantcode.com/2010/12/13/wpfcopy-uielement-to-clipboard-as-multiple-formats/ just that this doesn't use MVVM and that is exactly what I am after, how to do this in MVVM.

Comment: Are you trying to copy the data inside, or the whole item to the clipboard? who/what will use it how?

Comment: I had to do this before in MVVM.  I used a POCO interface that was resolved by Unity during application startup.  There were two implementations of the interface in a service layer: one which output to the console (for component testing), and one which did the dirty work.  This kept windows namespaces out of the view model, and left the view model dealing with an abstraction.